# Frontend magento 2 shows product in a category, but backend they are disabled

Tags: magento2, product, category, frontend, backend

Have 1 technical question that you may know about magento 2

I want to have on the frontend the bracelets products disabled under the clothing category.

The thing is, in the backend, they are disabled in the clothing category, that is why I cannot fix this for the frontend.

Someone know what I can do?

[image]

When you look at the picture, you see at the left side, in clothing category (135) products.... while you look down at products in category, it says only 37 found who are enabled.

The frontend shows possibly these 135 products.

So that is why I cannot disable the products because they are in this setup already disabled.

Meanwhile they keep appearing on frontend

Comment: Did you solve this, i'm getting this same issue

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't took care about the store view in your back office. They could be disabled in default store view, but enabled in specific store view.

Comment: Thanks you @claims ! Have checked every store view in backend, but same story for each store view, I will show picture in the question with a print screen, the category at the left side shows (135 products) while when you check products in category it shows 37 found

Comment: In frontend, products are more likely returned by elasticsearch who is using flat tables. You might not have reindex which might explain why the disabled products stills shows ? `bin/magento index:reindex`

Comment: Thank you, yes have done that many times, doesn't change this right now